# Question about Nearest

Tags: list-manipulation, filtering, nearest

In the following example `Nearest` finds the nearest values between `list1` and `list2` and resorts the `list2` according to the order in `list1`.

```
list1 = {1, 2, 4, 8, 16, 32};
list2 = {2.1, 1.1, 4.1, 16.1, 8.1, 32.1};

result=Nearest[list2, list1]

{{1.1}, {2.1}, {4.1}, {8.1}, {16.1}, {32.1}}
```

How can I find the indices on how `list2` was resorted to obtain `result`.

I would like to get the following as output:

```
{2, 1, 3, 5, 4, 6}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So you really want to find nearest from `list1` not `list2`, with labels, right?

```
 Nearest[Thread[# -> Range@Length@#] &@list1, list2]
```

> ```
> {{2}, {1}, {3}, {5}, {4}, {6}}
> ```

Comment: Yes, in my problem `list1` corresponds to starting coordinates of a constant number of particles in an image. `list2` would be the coordinates got from `ComponentMeasurements` in the next image (here the order can be different then in `list1`). I follow the particles and track them by using `Nearest` from image to image. The indices I need to resort also corresponding further properties like (`MeanIntensity`, `BoundingBoxArea`, etc.).

Answer (score 8):

This is the same approach as Kuba's, only a bit shorter

```
Nearest[list1 -> Automatic][list2]

(* {{2}, {1}, {3}, {5}, {4}, {6}} *)
```

Mathematica 10.0.2 or higher is required to take advantage of this listability.

Answer (score 5):

I would go with Kuba's method but this also works I believe:

```
list1 = {4, 16, 8, 1, 32, 2};
list2 = {2.1, 1.1, 4.1, 16.1, 8.1, 32.1};

Ordering[list1][[ Ordering @ Nearest[list1, list2] ]]
```

> ```
> {6, 4, 1, 2, 3, 5}
> ```

I scrambled the elements of `list1` so as not to make the problem too easy; if they are always in order this becomes simply `Ordering @ Nearest[list1, list2]`.

Comment: Yes this is generally the case, `list1` is not ordered.