# Better way to use Nearest

Tags: nearest

I'm trying to write a snippet of code that, given an input value (`value`), checks a list of arbitrary length (`data`) for the closest value, and then outputs the index of that value in the list. I'm using the output as an argument, so it can't be in brackets -- it has to be just the value. I can use `Nearest` and `Position` to get what I want, but it ends up being in a bunch of brackets each time and I need to use `First` or `Flatten` to get it out! It looks ugly.

Right now I have:

```
First[Flatten[Position[data, First[Nearest[data, value, 1]]]]]
```

The output is a value of position, not in brackets.

Without that `First` modifying `Nearest` the output is `{{}}`
Without that `First` and `Flatten` modifying `Position` the output is `{{position}}`. I need the output to simply be `position`.

Hopefully, I have explained my needs well - does anyone know of a more elegant way to accomplish this?

Comment: You can get rid of the Flatten and one of the Firsts: `First@Nearest[data -> Range[Length[data]], 5, 1]`

Comment: `First` + [(118679)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/118679/5478)

Comment: @bill s. Where in that function should the value you are matching go? The solution also has to work for a list of arbitrary length, which I should have mentioned - I will make the edit.

Comment: Duplicate?: [(25273)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/25273/121)

Comment: `data` is any list and I just used `5` as the value to match in the data vector

Answer (score 3):

I recommend not using `Position`, but rather giving `Nearest` a list of rules associating each item in your data list with its position.

```
data = {3, 4, 5, 6, 7};
rules = Thread[Rule[data, Range[Length[data]]]];
where[val_] := Nearest[rules, val, 1][[1]]

where /@ data
```

> `{1, 2, 3, 4, 5}`

Comment: ...or just use `Nearest[data -> Automatic, val, 1][[1]]`.

Comment: @J.M. Yes, that's more concise. Didn't know about that variant, but I guess I should have reviewed the docs before posting. Since the OP's case is very common, it makes a lot of sense it should have special support